# How can i combine different shape of matrix

Tags: numpy, torch

I am wondering how should i concatenate multiple tensors with different shapes into one tensor in torch or numpy.

Also, I want to fill the part where the shape of the two matrices is different with zero

i use this code

```
import numpy as np

n1 = np.array(np.random.rand(1,64,112,112))
n2 = np.array(np.random.rand(1,512,7,7))

np.concatenate((n1,n2))
```

but, i got error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-395-2f74879dd1d6> in <module>
      4 n2 = np.array(np.random.rand(1,512,7,7))
      5 
----> 6 np.concatenate((n1,n2))

ValueError: all the input array dimensions except for the concatenation axis must match exactly
```

Comment: What shape should the result be?  Your shapes are so different that you could easily end up with more 0s than non.

Comment: @hpaulji i use resnet18 and i wnat all output(feature map) of conv2d

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if there is a more straightforward way, but using [`pad`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.pad.html) to fill with zeros to match the maximum shape:

```
import numpy as np
from itertools import zip_longest

n1 = np.array(np.random.rand(1,64,112,112))
n2 = np.array(np.random.rand(1,512,7,7))

arrays = [n1, n2]

shapes = [n.shape for n in arrays] 

final = np.vstack(shapes).max(axis=0)

out = np.concatenate([np.pad(a, list(zip_longest([0], final-a.shape,
                                                 fillvalue=0)))
                      for a in arrays])

out.shape
```

Output shape: `(2, 512, 112, 112)`

Comment: If i wnat to combine 20 matrices do I use this code?
`code`
arrays = [n1 n2 n3 n4 ,,, n18 n 19 n20]

Comment: Yes, that's correct.